# determine if given differential equation is linear

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

let us consider following differential equation and problem statement

[image]

let us consider first of all $dy/dx$

$xdy=-(y^2-1)*dx$

or

$dy/dx=-(y^2-1)/x$

and

$dx/dy=-x/(y^2-1)$

they are reciprocal to each other,so how to clarify answer?please help me

UPDATED :

what about this  function?

[image]

Comment: for $dx/dy$ it is linear,for $dy/dx$ it is not linear right?

Comment: uhm, yes. Actually I mixed it up in my first comment ;-).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your comment, you are right.  $dx/dy$ is linear, whereas $dy/dx$ isn't.  Remember that you need to indicate the independent and dependent variables.  Here is how one simply approaches this problem:

If we have the equation of the form

$$\dfrac{dy}{dx}x + (y^2 - 1) = 0$$

Then the ODE is not linear; $x$ is the dependent variable and $y$ is the independent variable.  Thus, since the independent variable $y$ has the power of $2$ (not the order of derivatives).

If we have the equation of the form

$$(y^2 - 1)\dfrac{dx}{dy} + x = 0$$

Then $x$ is the independent variable and $y$ is the dependent variable.  Since all $x$ has the power of $1$, the ODE is linear.

---

For your other question, we have

$$t^3y^{(4)} - t^2y^{(2)} + 4ty' - 3y = 0$$

If $t$ is dependent and $y$ is independent, then the ODE is linear.

Comment: sorry what about if order is greater then $1$? for exmaple  like this  $t^3y^(4)$

Comment: If we have $t^3y^4$ in the ODE, then ODE is not linear, depending on ODE.

Comment: i will update my question

Comment: i have updated my question

Comment: Check my answer...

Comment: ok my friend,it is late now,good night